# Inbedded SQL in a Perl script issue with wildcard %

Tags: sql, perl

The below extract was taken from my Perl script which is failing because i need to escape the `%` symbol in the `NOT LIKE 'IE%'`. Does anyone know how i can do this easily?

```
my @oDests = keys %$d;

foreach my $nDestID (@oDests) {
    $sRes .= sprintf "\nSELECT * FROM symbol_destinations WHERE dest_id = %d AND symbol IN (SELECT sedol FROM symbols WHERE currency = 'GBX' AND ISIN NOT LIKE 'IE%')";
} # for each dest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf)/[sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf), you can use `%%` to insert the literal percent sign.